# fputcsv will only generate up to a 2.6kb file

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I'm creating a function to queries a database, loads into array, and then outputs to a CSV file.  The problem is that it truncates the file when it hits a size a 2.6kb.  Everything else works just fine.  Ive dumped the array everything is there before and after I create the CSV so I know that its not the array issue.  Here is the code.

```
    $rs = [];
    foreach($result as $r) {
        if($r['Valid'] == 1) {
            $r['Valid'] = 'Yes';
        } elseif($r['Valid'] == 0) {
            $r['Valid'] = 'No';
        }

        if($r['Border'] !== NULL) {
            $r['Border'] = 'Yes';
        } else {
            $r['Border'] = 'No';
            $r['County'] = ' - ';
        }
        $rs[] = $r;
    }

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($output, array('Zipcode', 'Count', 'Valid', 'Border', 'County'));
    foreach($rs as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }
    fclose($output);
```

$result is the defined as the return from the query.

The output is a CSV file that stops at 128 rows x 5 cols and truncates in the middle of populating 128th row and 4th column.  I'm stumped.

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1751
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1751
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

That is the output from ulimit -a

```
[Fri Oct 06 13:40:30 2017] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; h
ttpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Fri Oct 06 13:40:30 2017] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled
(wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Oct 06 13:40:30 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret
for digest authentication ...
[Fri Oct 06 13:40:30 2017] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Oct 06 13:40:31 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/
2 PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 06 13:40:38 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting
down
[Fri Oct 06 13:40:39 2017] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; h
ttpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Fri Oct 06 13:40:39 2017] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled
(wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Fri Oct 06 13:40:39 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret
for digest authentication ...
[Fri Oct 06 13:40:39 2017] [notice] Digest: done
"error_log" 37L, 3239C
```

Output from my error log.

Comment: Anything abnormal showing up in the error logs?

Comment: Does the loop die on iteration 128? Or does the file get truncated after the loop completes?

Comment: @AlexHowansky It loops all of the way through. I put a counter in the loop and echoed it after and it was at 452.

Comment: @AdamA  I am trying to access the logs right now, I'll let you know.

Comment: OK good, that's a significantly important bit of info, wasn't clear from the original post. Try skipping row 128, see if you get the same issue? Maybe some wacky values in that row borking your viewer?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Originally I was getting 224 rows when it was only 3 columns.  I added another column and now its only going 128 rows, so I don't think it has to do with the data in the rows.  It is however always 2.6kb that it stops at.

Comment: @AdamA Nothing peculiar in the error logs.

Comment: Maybe a super low `ulimit` on your shell?

Comment: Have you tried writing the output to a real file rather than php://output?

Comment: @AlexHowansky  How do I check that?

Comment: `ulimit -a` will report all current limits.

Comment: @NigelRen When I did that it truncated as well but on a different row of data.  The file was still the same 2.6kb

Comment: @AlexHowansky I added the output from that command

Comment: @BrockCaldwell Which PHP version on which OS are you using?

Comment: Try writing to a temporary:// file, see if it still truncated

Comment: @masterfloda PHP 5.6.3 -- CentOS 6.6

Comment: I have tested your code on PHP 5.3.6 and CentOS 6.6 as well as PHP 7.1.10 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with 400 rows of data with all 4 combinations of Valid and Border. It worked on both machines... Maybe you are running into some kind of memory limit or timeout. Have you tried running it on another machine? Have you turned on error logging? Is there anything in the PHP error logs? Or maybe you have a "bad" character in your $result. Try a simple `$result = array_reverse($result)`, maybe that will lead to the CSV being truncated at another position.

Comment: @masterfloda I tried the array_reverse to no luck.  I posted my error log.

Comment: Strange. Nothing in the error log... Btw, I made a typo, I tested PHP 5.6.3, not 5.3.6...  I'll have another go with PHP 5.6.30 (which your log says you are using).

Comment: @masterfloda  Thanks man I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem running it on PHP 5.6.30 on CentOS 6.6... I have no idea what causes your problem. But at least we know that it's neither your code, nor your environment... Have you tried running it via FPM? Maybe it's something with your CLI settings...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a coworker of mine to determine the underlying issues here.  It had to do with the way I was returning the file in the zend expressive HTML response.  I don't fully understand it but I know he is returning the file stream now and writing to a temporary file.

```
 $output = fopen('php://temp', 'wb+');
    //zend to Stream Interface to return expected Zend Expressive body
    $stream = new Stream($output);

    fputcsv($output, array('Zipcode', 'Count', 'Valid'));

    foreach($rs as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }

    return $stream;
```

This returns to the process method which returns the stream with the proper headers.

Thanks for the help everybody, sorry for the late response!